# Swift How to apply CIFilter to UIImage from UIGraphics?

Tags: swift, filter

I want to create a blur background from `UIImage`, however I am receiving the following error: *fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*
Help me out, please!

```
func createBackgroundImage(inputImage input:UIImage)->UIImage
{
let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let size = bounds.size

let scale = max(size.width / input.size.width, size.height / input.size.height)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1.0 / scale)
input.drawInRect(bounds)

var data:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
filter.setValue(data.CIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
return UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)!
}
```

The whole project can be found at https://github.com/larryhou/swift/tree/master/PhotoPreview

https://github.com/larryhou/swift/blob/master/PhotoPreview/PhotoPreview/PhotoPreviewController.swift
line:63

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686972/cant-extract-uiimage-from-ciimage-with-cifilter

Comment: Refer for update in swift-3 for filter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803763/ios-how-to-blur-a-image-with-cgpath/41185780#41185780